# Array push overwrite it's pervious element

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

orignal Array

```
[{
            "focusarea": "Leading Self",
            "focusarea_color": "#589681",
            "constructs": [
                {
                    "construct": "construct 1",
                    "construct_color": "#ee9696",
                    "questionsArray": [
                        {
                            "question": "Motivates and empowers others to achieve their goals",
                            "raterAnswers": [
                                {
                                    "raters": "Self",
                                    "raters_color": "#d5a12c",
                                    "answer": 2
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Manager",
                                    "raters_color": "#c95c5c",
                                    "answer": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Direct Report",
                                    "raters_color": "#1072c6",
                                    "answer": 4
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Peers",
                                    "raters_color": "#14d1b4",
                                    "answer": 4
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Stackholder",
                                    "raters_color": "#c471d8",
                                    "answer": 4
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Co-workers",
                                    "raters_color": "#69c3f4",
                                    "answer": 2
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Write your question here 10",
                            "raterAnswers": [
                                {
                                    "raters": "Self",
                                    "raters_color": "#d5a12c",
                                    "answer": 2
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Manager",
                                    "raters_color": "#c95c5c",
                                    "answer": 3
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Direct Report",
                                    "raters_color": "#1072c6",
                                    "answer": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Peers",
                                    "raters_color": "#14d1b4",
                                    "answer": 3
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Stackholder",
                                    "raters_color": "#c471d8",
                                    "answer": 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "raters": "Co-workers",
                                    "raters_color": "#69c3f4",
                                    "answer": 4
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
```

the array i want (this is result from console log)

```
[{
 focusarea: 'Leading Self',
 focusarea_color: '#589681',
 construct: 'construct 1',
 construct_color: '#ee9696',
 question: 'Motivates and empowers others to achieve their goals',
 answer: 3
}
{
 focusarea: 'Leading Self',
 focusarea_color: '#589681',
 construct: 'construct 1',
 construct_color: '#ee9696',
 question: 'Write your question here 10',
 answer: 3
}]
```

the array i get (this is result from third array variable)

```
{
  "focusarea": "Leading Self",
  "focusarea_color": "#589681",
  "construct": "construct 1",
  "construct_color": "#ee9696",
  "question": "Write your question here 10",
  "answer": 3
},
{
 "focusarea": "Leading Self",
 "focusarea_color": "#589681",
 "construct": "construct 1",
 "construct_color": "#ee9696",
 "question": "Write your question here 10",
 "answer": 3
},
```

my code

```
let lowestandHighestArray = []

for (let index = 0; index < detailedResultArray.length; index++) {
  let focusAreaArray = {};
  focusAreaArray.focusarea = detailedResultArray[index].focusarea // focus area name
  focusAreaArray.focusarea_color = detailedResultArray[index].focusarea_color // focus area color

  if(detailedResultArray[index].constructs) {
    let constructs = detailedResultArray[index].constructs

    for(let j = 0; j < constructs.length; j++) {
      focusAreaArray.construct = constructs[j].construct // construct name
      focusAreaArray.construct_color = constructs[j].construct_color // construct color

      let questionsArray = constructs[j].questionsArray
      for (let index2 = 0; index2 < constructs[j].questionsArray.length; index2++) {
          focusAreaArray.question = questionsArray[index2].question
          let answer = 0
          for (let index3 = 0; index3 < questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers.length; index3++) {
            answer = answer + questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers[index3].answer
          }
          focusAreaArray.answer = answer / questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers.length
          console.log(focusAreaArray);
          lowestandHighestArray.push(focusAreaArray)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

if I print result in console then it works as I want but if I push array into third variable then I get different result.

here, when ever I push new element to array at that time array overwrite its previous element I don't know the reason. can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: `push` does not overwrite anything. It only appends to an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it was array problem

i just move `let focusAreaArray = {};` inside the last loop and it's worked

```
let lowestandHighestArray = []

for (let index = 0; index < detailedResultArray.length; index++) {
  if(detailedResultArray[index].constructs) {
    let constructs = detailedResultArray[index].constructs
    for(let j = 0; j < constructs.length; j++) {
      let questionsArray = constructs[j].questionsArray
      for (let index2 = 0; index2 < constructs[j].questionsArray.length; index2++) {
        let focusAreaArray = {};
          let answer = 0
          for (let index3 = 0; index3 < questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers.length; index3++) {
            answer = answer + questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers[index3].answer
          }
          focusAreaArray.answer = answer / questionsArray[index2].raterAnswers.length
          focusAreaArray.focusarea = detailedResultArray[index].focusarea // focus area name
          focusAreaArray.focusarea_color = detailedResultArray[index].focusarea_color
          focusAreaArray.construct = constructs[j].construct // construct name
          focusAreaArray.construct_color = constructs[j].construct_color // construct color
          focusAreaArray.question = questionsArray[index2].question

          lowestandHighestArray.push(focusAreaArray)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `{}` is an object. Not an array.